# select2 dropdown auto width not working properly

Tags: jquery-select2

I am using select2 to set the `dropdownautowidth` to true on my SharePoint search page and it works perfectly on page load for the first time. After i search for some keyword, the page loads with search results and then dropdownautowidth is not setting true by somehow. I am using `$('#ddlCategory').select2({dropdownAutoWidth : true});` statement on my `document.ready` function.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 50):

This worked for me:

```
$('select').select2({
    dropdownAutoWidth : true,
    width: 'auto'
})
```

Comment: I needed the "width: 'auto'" too. Thanks!

Comment: Adding the "width: 'auto'" fixed a bug I was noticing in Firefox and IE. Thanks!

Comment: in my template there is a side bar which can get expanded so with width : '100%' worked for me.

Comment: This is definitively the answer !

Answer (score 14):

you need to quote it, like:

```
$('#ddlCategory').select2({dropdownAutoWidth: 'true'});
```

this works for me.

Answer (score 13):

In select2 4.0.0 this will not work for me, either. I use this workaround:

```
$('select').select2();
```

The css:

```
select + .select2-container {
  width: 100% !important;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I tried every solution here but what worked was:

```
width: '100%'
```

or

```
width: 'style'
```

and adding a style-attribute to the select-element, containing at least`width:100%`.

Answer (score 2):

Adjusting the CSS for the `.select2-container` class from `display: inline-block;` to `display: block;` worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

I just put the parameter `width: 'auto'` on the function call and then it works fine.

```
$('#months').select2({
    width: 'auto',
    allowClear: false,
    height: '100%',
});
```

Answer (score 0):

These adding these lines:

```
.select2-icon-result {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
}
```

to my main css file solved the problem of *"how to apply white-space:nowrap in autocomplete.ModelSelect2"* :

Answer (score 0):

For me this was the only thing i needed in order for the hidden selects to be 100%, just added a css class:

```
select, .select2-container { 
    display: block;
    width: 100% !important;
}
```

soelect2 version: 4.1.0-rc.0